# Linker warnings from wscc

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I am building a Mathematica interface to my c++ program. My makefile and source  are available at [github](https://github.com/andrewfowlie/thermal_funcs). [This is the line](https://github.com/andrewfowlie/thermal_funcs/blob/master/src/makefile#L29) that invokes `wscc`,

```
wscc -b64 -o math.exe math.tm math.c thermal_funcs.o zeta.o -lgsl -lgslcblas $(MATH_INC)
```

The `*.o` object files are linked successfully and `math.exe` is built by `wscc`. However, during the compilation stage, it appears that the object files are still passed to my C-compiler (they should only be passed during linking), such that I receive warnings:

```
math.c: gcc: warning: thermal_funcs.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: zeta.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
math.exe.tm.c: gcc: warning: thermal_funcs.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: zeta.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

I guess they are innocuous and the resulting executable `math.exe` works as expected. You can produce similar warnings by running

```
gcc -c test.c test.o
```

upon emtpy files `test.c` and `test.o` It seems like a (fairly harmless) bug in `wscc`, as it shouldn't be passing object files to `gcc -c` commands. But maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You do not need to use `wscc`/`mcc`.  You can use `wsprep`  to "compile" the `.tm` template to a `.c` file, then compile that file in a second step (and perhaps do the linking in a third).  The point of `wscc` is to avoid typing multiple commands. If you have a makefile anyway, it's more a hindrance to try to combine everything into a single command.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `src/makefile`, on the line that contains `$(MATH) -b64 ...`, 
change "`thermal_funcs.o zeta.o`" to "`-Wl,thermal_funcs.o,zeta.o`"  That's a lowercase ell after the W, not the digit 1.

And, then, of course,  `make math.exe`

The man page for `gcc` describes linker options.  "`-Wl,options`" is a way of passing options directly to the linker.  I don't know any more than that.

I tried your makefile, and got the two error messages.  Then I tried "`-Wl,options`" and the error messages went away.

Comment: That's great! Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/andrewfowlie/thermal_funcs#acknowledgements